# Cognitive batch transcription sentiment analysis

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, text-analytics-api

When using Azures batch transcription service ("api/speechtotext/v2.0/Transcriptions/") I am able to get sentiment analysis at the sentence level by setting the "AddSentiment" property to true. However, the results don't include sentiment analysis for the entire document like the the Text Analytics API.

Is there a flag for adding document level sentiment scoring?

I could calculate this myself but thought it would be nice if the API provided that feature:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-sentiment-analysis?tabs=version-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the V3 version of the api we removed the sentiment flag. We recommend using the text analytic api instead, as the capabilities are far superior to the limited analytics functionality we implemented. Text analytics also supports a variety of languages.